# Keras: convolutional layer for 1D input

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I can not build CNN for 1D input vector.

Example of input value:

```
df_x.iloc[300]
Out[33]:
0     0.571429
1     1.000000
2     0.971429
3     0.800000
4     1.000000
5     0.142857
6     0.657143
7     0.857143
8     0.971429
9     0.000000
10    0.000000
11    0.000000
12    0.000000
13    0.000000
14    0.000000
15    0.000000
Name: 300, dtype: float64
```

Example of output value:

```
df_y.iloc[300]
Out[34]:
0     0.571429
1     0.914286
2     1.000000
3     0.971429
4     0.800000
5     1.000000
6     0.914286
7     0.942857
8     0.800000
9     0.657143
10    0.857143
11    0.971429
12    0.000000
13    0.000000
14    0.000000
15    0.000000
16    0.000000
17    0.000000
18    0.000000
19    0.000000
20    0.000000
21    0.000000
22    0.000000
```

I have 15k traing examples.

```
df_x.shape
Out[28]:
(15772, 16)

df_y.shape
Out[29]:
(15772, 23)
```

My current model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(5, df_x.shape[1], input_shape=(5, 1)))
model.add(Dense(46, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(56, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(66, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(56, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(46, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(df_y.shape[1], activation='relu'))

# compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(df_x, df_y, epochs=5, batch_size=10)
```

I want to build model where first layer will be conv size `(5,1)`, 5 filters and input shape `df_x.shape[1], 1`.

I have an error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_10: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3
```

Can you explain me how can I build CNN for 1D input values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Conv1D` instead of `Conv2D` for that.

`Conv2D` is named 2-dimensional because it's designed to process images. However, the input to `Conv2D` is actually **4-dimensional** - `(batch, width, height, channels)`; the `channels` can be `3` for RGB or `1` for grey-scale images. That's why keras is complaining:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_10: expected
>   `ndim=4`, found `ndim=3`

`Conv1D` accepts **3-dimensional** input and that's exactly what you have (provided that you expand your `df_x` to `(15772, 16, 1)`). Also the `input_shape` argument must match the size of each row. Try this:

```
model.add(Conv1D(5, 5, input_shape=(df_x.shape[1], 1)))
```

Comment: Ok, it resolve issue with CNN layer. 
My current shape of df_x and df_y:

(15772, 16, 1) and (15772, 23, 1).

I have new error:

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_44 to have shape (12, 23) but got array with shape (23, 1). Why last layer has shape(12, 23)?

Comment: This error related to `Dense` layer, most probably the last one. What is the shape in the model? What does `model.summary()` show?

Comment: `12` is after the conv filter: `16 -> 12`, because the filter size is `5`. What do you want it to be?

Comment: I want to have a vector on an output. So size should be (1, 23). Is there any other option that using size filter 15 to reduce this size?

Comment: Yes, usually `MaxPooling1D` is used for this