# implementation of 1D convolutional neural network for tmie series classfication in keras R

Tags: r, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a 1D convolution neural net in keras R for time series classification. My training data consists of 1169 vectors. Where each vector contains 30 time points and has a categorical label (The total number of categories are 7 and I have encoded them using one hot encoded). My code is given as follows

```
model<-keras::keras_model_sequential() %>%
layer_conv_1d(filters = 30, kernel_size = 2 , activation = "relu",    
input_shape = c(1169, 30), strides = 1L)%>%
layer_max_pooling_1d()%>%
layer_conv_1d(filters = 15, kernel_size = 2, activation = "relu")%>%
layer_max_pooling_1d() %>%
layer_flatten() %>%
layer_dense(7, activation = "softmax")

model %>% compile(
optimizer = "adam",
metrics = 'accuracy',
loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
)
summary(model)
history<-model %>%
fit(training_data, 
  training_label,
  epochs= 100,
  batch_size = 32,
  validation_split = 0.3
)
```

After trying to fit the model, i get the following error

```
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
 ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_71_input to have 
 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1169, 30)
```

I know my question is similar to [Keras: convolutional layer for 1D input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739356/keras-convolutional-layer-for-1d-input) but i cant make it work. Firstly, I want to know what should be the appropriate size of output of the first convolutional layer (are there any good guesses as a starting point). Secondly can anyone refer me to a structured tutorial for single dimensional time series classification in Keras R, so that i learn the underlying theory in more detail and in interactive way. However, I will also appreciate a quick fix to the problem mentioned above, so that i can experiment on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you with your error message: `Conv1D` expects its `input_shape` argument to specify the length of the sequences but also the number of channels of the sequences it will see. And as always in Keras, the batch dimension should not be explicitly specified when defining the model. Therefore, with your current specification, your `Conv1D` layer expects to see sequences of length 1169 and with 30 channels each. To get the desired behavior, you should specify the `input_shape` as `(30,1)`.

Comment: Not appreciating the downvote here; give me a shout and I can remove my code; the answer is correct on itself.

Comment: I really hate people when they downvote and don't provide an explanation.

Comment: Yeah, i was able to find the exact reason that you are pointing on my own

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape your data so the number of features is the 3rd dimension it is asking for. In this case there is only 1 dimension of course. The shape of your input should be (1169, 30, 1). One option is using reshape2's melt function to get data in long format. Like this:

`library(reshape2)
long_training_data <- melt(training_data)`